# R - How can I find a duplicated line based in one Column and add extra text in that duplicated value?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I'am looking for a easy solution, instead of doing several steps.

I have a data frame with 36 variables with almost 3000 lines, one of vars is a char type with names. They must be unique. I need to find the rows with the same name, and the add "duplicated" in the text. I can't delete the duplicated because it is from a relational data base and I'll need that row ID for others operations.
I can find the duplicated rows and them rename the text manually. But that implies in finding the duplicated, record the row ID and them replace the text name manually.

Is there a way to automatically add the extra text to the duplicated names? I'am still new to R and have a hard time making auto condition based functions.

It would be something like this:
From this:

```
ID  name    age sex
1   John    18  M
2   Mary    25  F
3   Mary    19  F
4   Ben     21  M
5   July    35  F
```

To this:

```
ID  name                age sex
1   John                18  M
2   Mary                25  F
3   Mary - duplicated   19  F
4   Ben                 21  M
5   July                35  F
```

Could you guys shed some light?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would suggest a different approach, using an additional column to flag duplicates: `df$duplicated <- duplicated(df$name)`. Apart from being very simple and fast, it has the advantage of easy subsetting afterwards, for example `subset(df, !duplicated)`.

Comment: I thought about it something similar, but later I need to import the data to a database and It is not possible to add columns. I'am bound to the database they send me. Thanks for the advice, I'll certainly use in other works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the comment about adding a column is probably the best thing to do, but if you really want to do what you're suggesting...

The `duplicated` function will identify duplicates. Then, you just need to use paste to apply the append.

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:5,
    name = c('John', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Ben', 'July'),
    age = c(18, 25, 19, 21, 35),
    sex = c('M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Add "-duplicated" to every duplicated value (following Laterow's comment)
dup <- duplicated(df$name)
df$name[dup] <- paste0(df$name[dup], '-duplicated')

df
  ID            name age sex
1  1            John  18   M
2  2            Mary  25   F
3  3 Mary-duplicated  19   F
4  4             Ben  21   M
5  5            July  35   F
```

Comment: You can skip `newname` by just saying `dup <- duplicated(df$name); df$name[dup] <- paste(df$name[dup], "- duplicated")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for taking your time to help me with this. Much more simpler and efficient than my several steps. Thanks @user2133017, Laterow and docendo discimus. Regards mates.

Comment: What I also forgot to mention about the @docendo discimus idea of adding a new column, is that the Name column is 'unique' in the database, so unless a change the name, there is no way to add the duplicated lines in the database. But is a much better idea to just flag the duplicate ones.